# Log4J DailyRollingFileAppender fails to roll over

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using web-based application along with Log4J API for logging purpose.
In Log4J, I am using DailyRollingFileAppender to create a new log file for logging on each day.

here is my log4j properties file configuration

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf=ERROR  
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, jtiServiceAppender

log4j.appender.jtiServiceAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.jtiServiceAppender.File=${catalina.home}/logs/jti/ilume-mw${logfilename}-app.log
log4j.appender.jtiServiceAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.jtiServiceAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.jtiServiceAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH\:mm\:ss} %-5p %t [%C{1}]\: %m%n
```

**Problem:**
In my case, the log files are not created for each day. For the same when I checked my tomcat server log I have observed that I am getting an error as

> log4j:ERROR Failed to rename [D:\ilume-mwtmp0-app.log] to
>   [D:\ilume-mwtmp0-app.log.2019-07-09].

I have also referred the below link however still, I did not find a proper solution to my case.
**Link :** [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410189/log4jerror-failed-to-rename)

Any help or suggestion to solve this logging problem will be highly appreciated as it's been a couple of days and I am still not able to get any proper solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When adding `appender-ref` in `logger` tag, it throws renaming error. When adding `appender-ref` in `root` tag, it never throws that error.

Above is from below link. It seems same error and might help.

[log4j:ERROR Failed to rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410189/log4jerror-failed-to-rename)

Other than above, please check if there is permission issue at the directory where file needs to be renamed.